# Selenium can't click element obscure by "overlay" element

Tags: selenium, overlay, element

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <select id="buttonmodule" class="x2j" name="buttonmodule"> is not clickable at point (437,425) because another element <div id="overlay" class="r1_hide_busy_status r1_show_busy_status"> obscures it 
Message: Element <select id="buttonmodule" class="x2j" name="buttonmodule"> is not clickable at point (437,425) because another element <div id="overlay" class="r1_hide_busy_status r1_show_busy_status"> obscures it
```

I tried to find element id="buttonmodule" to click but I got message that it is not clickable by overlay element
XPATH of buttonmoduel: `"//a[contains(text(),'buttonmodule')]`
info of overlay: `<div id="overlay" class="r1_hide_busy_status" style="height: 967px; width: 1853px;" xpath="1"></div>`
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to my perception, your selected element is a dropdown developed using the `select` tag. Basically dropdown is developed using `select` tag will work by using `selectByVisibleText()` or `selectByValue()` or `selectByIndex()` methods as these are default methods to select values in the dropdown.

And we need to locate the dropdown and pass that object reference as an argument for select class nothing but associating both.

For example:-

```java
    Webelement dd = 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='buttonmodule']"));
    Select s=new Select(dd);
    s.selectByVisibleText("2");
```